# Is it possible to view saved gmail chat logs from Gmail in Outlook 2007 using Google Apps Sync?

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail, google-workspace, google-sync

I originally was going to post this to webapps.SE, but it's off-topic there due to asking about Outlook 2007.

After using Google Apps Sync to sync Outlook 2007 with a gmail account, I've run into a problem searching for saved chat logs in Outlook.  I have all of the saved folders in Outlook, but no chat folder.

I believe that the chats might not be saved as mail messages, or if they are they aren't synced.

Is it possible to view saved gmail chat logs from Gmail in Outlook 2007 using Google Apps Sync?

Comment: I believe this is a setting in your gmail interface - to let chat logs appear over IMAP.

Comment: I checked that box for the chat label with no effect.  That's what I thought at first, too, as it wasn't checked by default.

Comment: Perhaps Outlook doesn't check for new imap folders as often.. Did you try something silly like closing Outlook and reopening it after that change? Sounds like you have that covered... Still, just a thought..

Comment: Did that.  I am beginning to think that this is not a supported feature of Google Apps Sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [isn't a supported feature](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en/us/support/enterprise/static/gapps/art/users/en/glook/google_apps_sync_chart.pdf) of Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook.